# How to import an async function from another action (redux)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I want to import an async function from one action to another action in `redux`, but it's always throwing this error:

[image]

However, if I put it into the same file as the method that's calling the function it's working.

That's my function:

```
async function getStuff(uid, callback) {
  await firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/stuff').once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      callback(snapshot.val());
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

and that's how I call the function:

```
await getStuff(uid, async() => {
   // some stuff
});
```

and that's how I import it:

```
import { getStuff } from './stuff_actions';
```

Comment: What about making it exportable? `export async function getStuff(){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also have to export the function from the file in which you function exists

```
export async function getStuff(uid, callback) {
  await firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/stuff').once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      callback(snapshot.val());
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```